# Did anyone on the Avenger's side die on screen during the last battle of the Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

The Avenger's side implies everyone joining the battle against Thanos, from the mystic art warriors to Valkyrie.

Of course, this doesn't include,

> Tony Stark who has died after the battle.

Comment: Presumably some die when it “rains fire” but I’d have to try and find a video to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the casualty you mention in your question, there are no deaths that are shown on screen. That being said, I'm sure the Avengers' armies suffered serious casualties (seeing as this was a war between two huge armies). But none of these deaths were shown on screen.